# Date vs Strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to research the pros and cons to storing a date(ex: 2018-05-09) as a String(varchar) vs a Date datatype in mySQL workbench for an assignment(where I'll be comparing dates from different tables). In my class, the professor strongly advises AGAINST using Dates, as he says they are rarely interoperable. However, this leads me to question, if they seem to be interoperable, why would you use them over a varchar in the first place, if its seemingly niche use doesn't even seem to have any pros over a string? Personally I've found success in using the Date datatype, but I don't want to hold on to a bad habit if it really is inefficient.

I've even seen things where you can easily change the formatting with our format command, whereas I don't know how you would compare dates (which comes before or after) with strings in a query.

Any insight is helpful - again, I'm not looking for an answer to the query, but I can't seem to find any useful articles that compare the pros/cons of storing a Date as a string

Comment: Store dates as dates. There are no cons to it.

Comment: Your professor is really unqualified. Interoperability is easily solved with translation layer if ever needed, date performs better, easier to sort & filter, takes less disk space and RAM compared to a string.

Comment: I can't imagine what your prof means by "they are rarely interoperable". Store dates as dates. StackOverflow is filled with questions from people who are facing problems because they stored dates as strings and now want to do comparisons that aren't possible.

Comment: BTW: Where is your professor working?  (I need to know, and not go to that school....)

Comment: It is said "if you can't do it, teach it". Your professor is wrong about this in any way you look at it. I suggest attempting to find a better professor.

Comment: See a detailed explanation of why a date type is the only sane choice in [Should I use DATE or VARCHAR in storing dates in MySQL?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422047/should-i-use-date-or-varchar-in-storing-dates-in-mysql) over on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it safe to store dates as a string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619860/is-it-safe-to-store-dates-as-a-string-in-mysql).

Comment: The problem with IT professors is that they learn enough to teach and then they spend so much time teaching they no longer have time to improve their knowledge. IT is a very fast moving topic and each programming language and concept can be reviewed in 18-24 months, unlike for example metalwork which changes over many decades rather than months.

Comment: Your teacher has a point in that datatype definitions and what can be stored can vary wildly between sql dialects for example sqlserver has smalldatetime which does not exist in mysql also datetime2 , The supported range for a date datatype in mysql is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31' in mysql and 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 in sql-server  and I'm sure there are more to be discovered across the dialects.

Comment: I would still use an appropriate date type to store a date though and live with the fact that code developed in 1 dialect may need to be refactored in another. BUT there may be an argument for storing dates in a vendor neutral format such as varchar.

Comment: @P.Salmon I agree there is value in developing apps in a vendor neutral way. However, [my very personal opinion is that] the downside of storing dates as string far outweights the possible benefits.

Comment: @The Impaler I don't disagree , but thought it worth pointing up some dialect differences the OP may not have been aware of but which may be where the teacher was coming from.

Comment: It would be appropriate to ask your professor, "can you show me an example of an SQL date value that is not interoperable?"