# Why is my professor saying storing Dates as Dates are incorrect?(Varchar)

Tags: mysql, varchar

I am taking a course at a public uni in the US. Currently, we are learning databases(mySQL) where we are storing dates in ISO format: (2020-01-29), I was originally storing them as Dates, because I assumed its a Date, so it should obviously be stored as such. However, I have been informed by the professor and multiple TAs that storing them as VARCHARs are better, as Dates are handled differently in different versions of mySQL, and that dates, when stores as dates, are not usually interoperable. I've obviously researched this topic online, and can't find any reason to store them as VARCHAR over date. Is my professor(and TAs) wrong, what would make them think this way? Or am I just being stubborn?

Comment: *that storing them as VARCHARs are better* If this is what's being taught then no wonder there are so many SO questions about poor performance and issues with dates. I don't know if there's a specific MySql reason but a date is *not* a string.

Comment: your professor and TAs are wrong.

Comment: See discussion on this SO question, posted six days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71589456/20860 I wonder if you're in the same class.

Comment: Your professor is objectively wrong. Do what the ask for the class, but please don't ever store dates as varchar in real-life.

Comment: You should ask the professor for an example case of a date that is "not interoperable." (I posted this same suggestion on the other SO question I linked to.)

Comment: I thought of one case that might have given your professor this opinion. "Zero" dates like 0000-00-00 were allowed in older versions of MySQL, but with the default strict mode of newer versions, these bogus dates will cause errors. You can change the sql mode to allow them, but it's a much better idea to avoid using invalid date values.

Comment: It looks like his personal opinion and nothing else. Could you ask the professor to back his claim (interoperability issues, different behavior) with facts?

Comment: This also makes me wonder what else this professor is teaching the class. 